# MouseDragged not released when dragging on other views

Tags: cocoa, drag-and-drop, nsview, nsresponder

I have 2 subclasses of NSView that are subviews to a common superview. They dont overlap and they both intercept mousedragged calls. When I drag from one of the subclasses to the other the mousedragged function will be called until I release the mouse button even when I drag all over the screen. I though the default behavior was for the mousedragged function to be called only when the mouse was over the bounds of the receiver.
Iam also using NSTrackingArea for mouse enter, exit and move events, but from what I've been reading does not involve drag events

Thank you for your time,
Jose.

Comment: That is the normal behaviour. What is your question?

Comment: Well, I was getting a different behavior before, and unfortunately I don't know what did I changed. The mousedragged event was jumping to the other subclass view immediately when entering it's bounds. And that's what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could subclass the `NSWindow` and override `sendEvent:`. That way, you can intercept the `NSLeftMouseDragged` events and dispatch them in whatever way you wish.

Comment: Thanks Tom, this sounds better.. What I ended up doing was to call [super mousedragged] on both subviews, and then the superview will call a [subview distributed_mouseDragged] depending on the location.